# "Expected class-name"...Issue in destructor implementation

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, stack, destructor

I'm trying to implement a stack and a queue. I've also been provided with a code to test both the stack and a queue (to see whether their respective functions work properly).

I've implemented functions of both the stack and quete,, but when trying to compile them I get the error:
*In destructor `Stack::~Stack()'
expected class-name before '(' token*
in both of them.

Following is the generic Stack class:

```
template <class T>
class Stack
{
    List<T> list;
 public:

    Stack();

    Stack(const Stack<T>& otherStack);

   ~Stack();
}
```

The List class:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
    ListItem<T> *head;

    public:

    List();

    List(const List<T>& otherList);

    ~List();
}
```

Now the destructor for the List class is working just fine. So keeping that in mind, my implementation for the destructor was:

```
template <class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{

                 list.~List();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't call the destructor explicitly - the language takes care of that for you.

Comment: Lose the `list.~List()` call. That member will self-destruct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should (almost) never call a destructor explicitly. When your `Stack`'s life ends, it will automatically call the destructors of its members. You don't need to do anything. `list` will be destroyed automatically.

If you had a pointer, `p`, to a dynamically allocated object as a member, *then* you would need to do some cleaning up in the destructor by doing `delete p;`. But here, you don't. `list` will be destroyed automatically.

Comment: @WhozCraig Added an "almost". :D

Comment: Silly rabbit =P Really nice answer, btw.

Comment: Nitpick: `list` doesn't necessarily technically have automatic storage duration, it has the same storage duration as the `Stack<T>` object containing it.

Answer (score 5):

Your `list` member is an automatic variable. Its lifetime (the time when its constructor and destructor are callled) is managed by the language. As soon as the containing object goes out of scope, the `List` destructor will be called.

That said, there are valid reasons to call a destructor explicitly (you don't have one and you rarely will) and to actually do it you need to specify the type correctly.

In your case that would be

```
list.~List<T>();
```

`List` itself is a template, not a type.